# unmet dependencies when simulating the installation of ros-kinetic-desktop?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on OS- 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04 ( LTS ) architecture - ARM64  , and trying to simulate installation of `ros-kinetic-desktop` using

```
sudo apt-get install -s ros-kinetic-desktop
```

However, I am ending up with the error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    ros-kinetic-desktop:Depends: ros-kinetic-viz but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

Can someone please suggest what I am missing here ? Thank you

PS: I tried simulating installation of `ros-base` and it seems to be working fine.
Another note is that I have skipped `sudo apt-get update`and just added the ROS sources list manually to software and updates .( This is to avoid updating the packages from all repositories since the system I'm working on might crash with the newer versions of these packages )

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255670/unmet-dependencies-when-simulating-the-installation-of-ros-kinetic-desktop-?/) by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2017-02-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-02-27**:
Please provide enough information to reproduce your problem. What is your full architecture armhf or arm64? What is your OS, full version? etc.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-28**:\

> Another note is that I have skipped sudo apt-get updateand just added the ROS sources list manually to software and updates

So how exactly do you expect `apt-get` to know where to find packages then?

Also: `apt-get update` does not touch any packages. It just *downloads* the index.

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-02-28**:
So, when I manually add the ROS sources list to software & updates applet and hit reload, the apt-cache is loaded with the ROS packages and I am able to find them.

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-02-28**:
Although `apt-get update` alone isn't a problem, when I will perform `apt-get install` after updating ,there is a high chance that I end up installing the updated versions of the dependencies (system) which might not be supported by the system I'm working on.

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-02-28**:
Also, initially I just installed roslaunch package with the same procedure ( without explicit 'apt-get update' ) perfectly fine and then I removed the package (`apt-get purge` and `apt-get autoremove`) and checked the --simulate installation of desktop version and it didn't throw up this error then?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-28**:
Ubuntu ('upstream') has a version of some of the ROS pkgs in the default repositories (see [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python/python-roslaunch) for `roslaunch` fi). It could well be that that is what `apt-get` used when you didn't add the ROS package repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Note that mixing pkgs in the default repositories with those on the OSRF repositories is not supported (and if you add the ROS repositories will also not happen by default).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0